# SnarQube Issue resolution null inside compute() method

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

In my class that implements MeasureComputer, I am getting a issue resolution status null.
FYI: I can read issue type, but not issue resolution.

Need help on this. Here is my code snippet.

```
------------------------------------------
import org.sonar.api.ce.measure.Issue;
------------------------------------------

public void compute(MeasureComputerContext context)

    {
    List<? extends Issue> issues= context.getIssues();

    //For each issue in issues resolution status is null.
    issue.resolution() is null ..

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

null resolution means that issue is unresolved (status is open, reopened or confirmed).